# Data binding doesn't work with my dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I'm developing a WPF application with .NET Framework 4 and [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)
I created a custom user control which only contains a *DataGrid*:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="PadacEtl.Matcher.Views.LaraDataGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    DataContext="{Binding}">

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Model.Value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

This control defines a dependency property *SelectedItems*:

```
public partial class CustomDataGrid : UserControl
{
    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>),
            typeof(CustomDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new List<ItemViewModel>()));

    public CustomDataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        SelectedItems = dataGrid.SelectedItems.Cast<ItemViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Finally, this custom user control is used in a view, defined as follow:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Project.Views"
    Title="Project"
    Height="700" Width="1050"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <uc:CustomDataGrid DataContext="{Binding Items}"
            SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With the corresponding *ViewModel*:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

    private IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> selectedItems = new List<ItemViewModel>();
    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return selectedItems; }
        set
        {
            if (value != selectedItems)
            {
                selectedItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItems);
             }
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //Something useful to feed Items
    }
}
```

**My problem is**: When I select one or more rows from my *CustomDataGrid*, *SelectedItems* from *MainViewModel* is not updated. I think I didn't wired something well but I don't find what.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have a two-way binding on your `SelectedItems` property. Either you do that explicitly in the binding expression like this:

```
<uc:CustomDataGrid ... SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

or you set the [FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) flags in the dependency property declaration:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedItems",
        typeof(IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>),
        typeof(CustomDataGrid),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

---

Note also that it is bad practice to set the default property value to a new collection instance, as that collection would be used as default value for all "instances" of the property. In other words, the default value of the `SelectedItems` property on two instances of CustomDataGrid would be the same collection object. If you add items to the one, the items would also be contained in the other. You have to set the default value in the constructor of the control.

---

**Edit**: After taking a second look at your UserControl and how you bind its properties, I realized that it can't work the way you designed it. Setting the DataContext as done in your binding declaration

```
<uc:CustomDataGrid DataContext="{Binding Items}"
    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"/>
```

would require to explicitly set the binding source object of the `SelectedItems` binding, perhaps like this

```
SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems, Source={StaticResource myViewModelInstance}}"
```

Instead of doing that, your control should have a bindable `Items` or `ItemsSource` in addition to the `SelectedItems` property. You could then simply write your bindings like this:

```
<uc:CustomDataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource myViewModelInstance}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"/>
```

Comment: I added both but this doesn't work much. I also double checked binding errors in output windows and it seems ok. So everything seems to be well wired.

Comment: Thank you, this now works like a charm and the code looks better. Your answer is now accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the List to observablecollection, because observablecollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged where as list doesn't do so

Comment: I tried but it didn't work because I do not update the *List* with methods like *Add* or *Remove*, I create a new *List* so the reference is different.